# Entity Framework 4.3.1 , DbContext Adding an object with existing referenced object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, poco

( first of all sorry for the bad english )

I am new to the entity framework and I do a little bit of testing. Lets assume I've got 2 Objects that are POCO Objects. Person and Address.

My scenario is that I want to add a new Person to the DbContext that has a reference to an already existing Object. The connection between both entities is a Many : Many relation.

```
 using ( var t = new Tww.SV.Models.Model.Portal.SVPortalEntities() )
 {
       testaddress = ( from c in t.Adresses
                       select c ).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
 }

 var newPerson = new Person();
 newPerson.Name = "Henry";
 newPerson.Adresses.Add( testaddress );

 using ( var k = new Tww.SV.Models.Model.Portal.SVPortalEntities() )
 {
       k.Persons.Add(newPerson);
       k.SaveChanges();
 }
```

The Problem I do now have is that an **additional** Address ( with same values but a new Key ) will be created once the Person is added. How can I add the existing reference to the new object instead of creating a new one ?

Comment: Simplest approach would be to override SaveChanges, iterate through all entities and those that are already saved (Id > 0) set them to "Unchanged" or, if you want to persist eventually made changes, "Modified"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one context for the whole operation:

```
 using ( var t = new Tww.SV.Models.Model.Portal.SVPortalEntities() )
 {
       testaddress = ( from c in t.Adresses
                       select c ).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
       var newPerson = new Person();
       newPerson.Name = "Henry";
       newPerson.Adresses.Add( testaddress );
       k.Persons.Add(newPerson);
       k.SaveChanges();
 }
```

If you can't do that, then you need to manually change the state of the existing address in the new context via the ObjectStateManager or similar.

Comment: In the end I used those self tracking objects

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you need to do this within two separate instances of the data context? I assume you do and that you're just providing a simplified example, but if not, then using the same context instance across the entire code would solve your problem.

However, this is a common problem, particularly when using EF classes across services like WCF. The best solution I've found is to "fix up" the incoming new objects before saving them. I'll be the first to admin I find this "ugly" but I also have failed to find any better options that actually work all the time. I usually put the reference re-association code into a method in another partial class segment of my entity class:

```
public void FixUp(EntityContext c)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < this.Addresses.Count; i++)
  {
    var existing = c.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id = this.Addresses[i].Id);
    if (existing != null)
    {
      this.Addresses[i] = existing;
    }
  }
}

using (var k = new EntityContext())
{
  newPerson.FixUp(k);
  k.Persons.Add(newPerson);
  k.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain why this happens: You are creating two DbContexts. In the first, you retrieve an adress object. Then, outside of any Context scope (see your *using* ) you are creating a new *detached* person. It does not belong to either of your two contexts. The next thing that happens is that you create a new context and add your *Person* object to it.

This context now does not know your new *Person* (it was "out of scope", or *Detached*) nor your *Adress* (It is from another context). Both entities will be added and marked as such in the ChangeTracker, *Added*.

You have multiple solutions:

- First, use only one context to retrieve your *Adress*, create your *Person* in and *Add* it. You need to change your code a bit for this and it might not work out for you if you are working on a service based scenarios.
- Second, if you have no chance of changing this code and you need to attach detached objects, like you do in your code snippet, you might want to override *SaveChanges* of your Context class, and iterate through the entities in the *ChangeTracker*. Those that are already saved (Id > 0) may be set to "Unchanged" or, if you want to persist eventually made changes, "Modified". This feels ugly, but it should work.